# pthreads mutex without global variable, only return arrays in thread_struct

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

Hi once more everyone!

I am implementing a calculation function, that runs through a big array of numbers and should therefore be cut into small snippets all calculated by single threads. Using less than 8 threads & dividiable by 2 it runs okayish (small error, using one thread, so n_threads = 1, gives the correct result!).

Question: "So I was wondering if I need mutexes if I never access a global variable?"

Explanation status quo: I have a `double sum` then I create the threads and run the calculation through the array by parts. 
In the end I take all partial sums and add them up to my sum in the main program. Then I add the rest of the array, that was not divided into the threads (for example in the case having a total array length of 10 and 4 threads: which would give 8 array elements to the threads and 2 have to be calculated additionally). This seems not to be the correct way, I fear. I am not deep enough into the topic yet, so I am not sure if I have to lock some access somewhere to the sum in the main program.

The main-code:

```
  double sum = 0;
  // arr, p and n_threads are given into this as input to a function

  pthread_t threads[n_threads];
  struct thread_input thread_args[n_threads];
  int thread_size = total_elemts/n_threads;

 for (int t = 0; t < n_threads; t++){
    thread_args[t].tid = t;
    thread_args[t].start = t*thread_size;
    thread_args[t].end = ((t+1)*thread_size)-1;
    thread_args[t].arr = arr;
    thread_args[t].p = p;
    thread_args[t].part_sum = 0;
    pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, thread_number, (void*) &thread_args[t]);
   }

 for (int t = 0; t < n_threads; t++){
    pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    printf("thread %d %15.10lf\n", t, thread_args[t].part_sum);
    sum += thread_args[t].part_sum;
 }
return sum;
```

The number_thread:

```
void* thread_number(void* arg){
    struct thread_input *param = (struct thread_input*)arg;

    int i;
    for(i = param->start; i <= param->end; i++){
      param->part_sum += Func1(param->arr[i]);
    }

    for(i = param->start; i <= param->end-1; i+=2){
      param->part_sum += Func2(param->arr[i], param->arr[i+1]);
    }

    for(i = param->start; i <= param->end-3; i+=4){
      param->part_sum += Func3(&param->arr[i], param->p);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Is this okay without locks or have I missed something else?
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_join()` is specified by POSIX (*Base Definitions, 4.12 Memory Synchronization*, POSIX is available at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) to synchronize memory with respect to other threads, so no, you don't need a mutex, the assignment to `thread_args[t].part_sum` by `thread_number()` is visible to the main code after `pthread_join()`.

Answer (score 1):

Locking is not required because *sum* is only accessed in the serial part of the code.

The small error/variation in the result most likely stems from changing the order of summation, i.e. when you accumulate the sum in a single thread, and the value of the sum becomes big, then small additional values might be numerically ignored and this can accumulate to a significant error. Summing partial sums first alleviates this problem, and hence, the multi-threaded result is probably more accurate.

When in doubt about proper multi-threaded access to variables in you code you might consider compiling and running the program with a [thread sanitizer](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/12/02/address-and-thread-sanitizers-gcc/) enabled.

As a side note, nothing is assigned to the member *param->buf* in your example code.

Comment: hej thanks okay so I got that at least right with mutexes. I will try out to improve it according to your comment about the order. Computer numbers still mess with my mind somehow ...

About your side note: renaming to fit better to the text, and ofc I have overseen one buf ^^

Comment: would it be better, from a computational pov, to use a global sum maybe?

Comment: Always using a global sum is quite the opposite, since in the worst case the error grows proportional to the number of elements to be added. One method to actually reduce the summation error is the [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).